# too little fps in android emulator / wrong error message at start

Tags: java, android, android-intent, emulation, android-activity

I have an app that, for now, runs a loop where it updates the game state ~25 times/s and tries so draw it 40 times/s. the update works fine, it shows just a bit more than 25. but on the emulator, the game draws under 20 fps, no matter how much there is to draw. even if I only paint the background green it has low fps.

I sent the app to someone who tested it on his phone, there it runs correctly with 40fps drawing speed and 25fps updating speed.

I tested it on the emulator with different API levels, the drawing fps is always way too slow. I use eclipse. do I have to make any special setting for the emulator or so?

There was another problem too, the guy who tested it on his phone got an error message when starting the app, it said the app wouldn't react and the option for wait and shutdown. after waiting 5-10 seconds the content view would be displayed. I create the content view and assign the variable in the `onCreate` method, without starting the loop. In the `onStart` method I set the `contentView` and start the loop, but it runs an empty while loop until I set a `boolean` in the `onResume` method. any ideas?

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 view= new MainMenu(this); }

protected void onStart() { 
super.onStart(); 
this.setContentView(view); 
view.startGameView();
}

 public void startGameView() {
 loop=new GameLoop(this); 
loop.start();
 }

protected void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 view.resumeGameView();
} 

public void resumeGameView() { 
loop.b_pause=false;//loop starts to execute code for drawing/updating
 }
```

the code for the activity change:

```
public void changeActivity(Class c, String str)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, c);
        startActivity(i);       

    }
```

Comment: It may help if you post some code, at least for `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()` and the game loop.

Comment: Please, add the code in your question. Edit the question and insert the code there.

Comment: In the code you pasted I don't see anything anormal. Can you post the MainMenu code?
Have you tested on other phones besides your friend's one?

Comment: btw the fps rate highly increases for a very short time if I end the app, by running it again for example.

Comment: Why would you have a higher rendering rate than update rate?

Comment: I read this article: http://www.koonsolo.com/news/dewitters-gameloop/ 25 updates per second would be enough for the human eye I believe, more renders per second make it more smooth though. but it doesnt matter since my emulator has less fps than updates.

Comment: I think you should post the code from MainMenu class.

Comment: actually it isnt the main menu class but the level class with several hundret lines of code. I cant post so much. but I can put it on pastebin if you want. the gameview class and the classes that have gameview as base class: http://pastebin.com/TEAe5Mcb